# Cassandra consistency issue on cluster system

Tags: cassandra, hector

**Background**:
My application is running on a cluster system(which have 4 nodes), and system time of these four nodes are synchronizing by NTP. I use Write.QUORUM and Read.QUORUM strategy. The probability of this problem is not very high. Cassandra version is 1.0.3, I have tried Cassandra 1.1.1, this problem is still exist.

**Problem**:
I deleted a column, but after 6 seconds, Cassandra can still get the old record which "isMarkedForDelete" is still false.

Is anybody meet the same problem? And how to solve it?

**Detail**: See the log below:

Node 3(Local node):
[pool-2-thread-42] 2012-06-27 **14:49:23,732** SliceQueryFilter.java (line 123) collecting 0 of 2147483647: SuperColumn(667072 [......`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**false**:36@1340779097312016,......)

[pool-2-thread-44] 2012-06-27 **14:51:21,367** StorageProxy.java (line 172) Mutations/ConsistencyLevel are [RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**true**:4@1340779881338000,]),])])]/QUORUM

> -- I delete this record at 14:51:21,367

[pool-2-thread-37] 2012-06-27 **14:51:27,400** SliceQueryFilter.java (line 123) collecting 0 of 2147483647: SuperColumn(667072 [......,`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**false**:36@1340779097312016,......)

> -- But I can still get the old record at 14:51:27,400

Node2:
[MutationStage:118] 2012-06-27 **14:51:21,373** RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 48) Applying RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**true**:4@1340779881338000,]),])])

[MutationStage:118] 2012-06-27 **14:51:21,374** RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 60) RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**true**:4@1340779881338000,]),])]) applied.  Sending response to 6692098@/192.168.0.3

[MutationStage:123] 2012-06-27 14:51:27,405 RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 48) Applying RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [......,`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**false**:36@1340779097312016,......])

[MutationStage:123] 2012-06-27 **14:51:27,405** RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 60) RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [......,`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**false**:36@1340779097312016,.......]),])]) applied.  Sending response to 6698516@/192.168.0.3

Node1:
[MutationStage:98] 2012-06-27 **14:51:24,661** RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 48) Applying RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**true**:4@1340779881338000,]),])])

[MutationStage:98] 2012-06-27 **14:51:24,675** RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 60) RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`: **true** :4@1340779881338000,]),])]) applied.  Sending response to 6692099@/192.168.0.3

[MutationStage:93] 2012-06-27 **14:51:40,932** RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 48) Applying RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**true**:4@1340779900915004,]),])])

DEBUG [MutationStage:93] 2012-06-27 **14:51:40,933** RowMutationVerbHandler.java (line 60) RowMutation(keyspace='drc', key='3332', modifications=[ColumnFamily(fpr_index [SuperColumn(667072 [`7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`: **true** :4@1340779900915004,]),])]) applied.  Sending response to 6706555@/192.168.0.3

[ReadStage:55] 2012-06-27 **14:51:43,074** SliceQueryFilter.java (line 123) collecting 0 of 5000: `7fffffffffffffff000001382ca96c8b636b698a`:**true**:4@1340779900915004

Node 4:

There is no log about this record on Node 4.

Comment: Is your replication factor 3? (looks like it from the logs, but please confirm). What does `nodetool ring` say?

Comment: Could you paste here how you create the keyspace and the table from which your are deleting the column?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid depending on deletions in Cassandra, as they're generally not reliable.

See http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/8-axel-liljencrantz-23204252 (slide 34 onwards in particular). Forcing a major compaction may fix the issue.